# OPE Encryption using Java and Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I need to enable OPE encryption in my application in which I'm letting a user create a new table through a JSP page. All the table entries will be encrypted using *OPE (Order Preserving Encryption)* encryption for which I've decided an algorithm called **ROPE (Random OPE)** in which all details are encrypted with a random generated key using any encryption algorithm and these encrypted values will be given an encoding based on avl tree representation of these values. I am using *RSA* for encrypting these user entered values. I was thinking about adding a new column, when creating new encrypted table in MySql database, whenever the type of a stored value is 'int' and to store encodings of these encrypted integers to compare next time when a user will process a range query.
Currently I'm only able to create a new encrypted table in database as the user enters the details in it. But I can not think of how to achieve the rest of its part (performing AVL tree encodings for encrypted integers and storing encodings in the same table).
Here is the algorithm if I was not able to tell you the whole scenario...
A **Randomized Order-Preserving Encryption** scheme is
defined as ROPE= (K, Enc, Dec) executed by a trusted proxy
P and a server S, where K is the key, Enc is encryption and
Dec is decryption. Enc and Dec are interactive.
1. K is generated randomly at P : K=RND.key
2. Enc(V, K) runs at P and S:
P calculates C←Enc (V, K) and sends C to S.
If C is present in S, S returns encoding E of C to P
Else go to step 3.
3. AVL Tree searches for V as follows:
The trusted proxy executes OPE algorithm to get encoding values.
P asks for the root of AVL tree to get ciphertext C′.
P obtains V′ by decrypting C'.
P orders AVL tree, if V 
Repeat until AVL tree finds a node with a null value in the tree.
After inserting C into the AVL tree, it gets the tree encoding of C and then calculates E of C and puts it in database table. For any insertion operation, a ciphertext Cf or V is already in the AVL Tree, the tree server simply increments node‟s counter value which is initially set to zero. Otherwise, the server will inserts C into the AVL tree with counter set to 1 and stores it in table.
During the deletion process, the server decrements node‟s counter value. If the counter value becomes zero, the node is deleted from the tree and also removes it from the table.
4. Dec(E, K) runs at S and P:
S returns E to P as a result of query retrieval.
P communicates with S to get ciphertext C for the corresponding E
P returns v←Dec(C, K) to the client.
_any help will be grateful and **Thanks** in advance. _

Comment: Wondering what is the reason to use asymmetric (RSA) encryption over symmetric (ex: AES) encryption considering the speed and data size tradeoffs?

Comment: @_zaph_ But that's not the problem. The problem is how to use the other part (encoding encrypted values). Thanx by the way

Comment: I didn't say it was a/the problem, just interested in the reason for the choice. Please consider it research, I am interested in why developers make choices between different methods.

Comment: @zaph "Oh. The reason is pretty simple. RSA implementation is pretty easy and also another fact is that, after OPE, I'll need additional and multiplicational homomorphic encryptions to use; and RSA is already multiplicational homomorphic. Hence, it saves me a different encryption algorithm. :)

Comment: So it is not for the separate public/private keys? Neither the ~1000x speed penalty nor data limited to key size are indues. OK, like I said I am just interested in how decisions are made in general. Good luck with an OPE implementation.